# subsampling numpy array; distribution remains same in test and train

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I want to subsample a numpy array (shape = (0,n)), such that distribution of elements in train and test remains approximately same or there should be atleast one element in train and test of each class. eg:

```
a = [1,2,3,1,3,3,2,1,2,1]
train = [1,1,2,2,3,3]
test = [1,1,2,3]
```

I want to subsample my parameters and outputs based on the outputs. For now, I am using np.random.choice to take random indexes. Is there any way i can check for distribution in python

Comment: If your data set is large enough, compared to the number of unique elements, `np.random.choice` should do the work.

Comment: It's small ~100

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `collections` built-in library from Python.

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> a = [1,2,3,1,3,3,2,1,2,1]
>>> count_a = Counter(a)
>>> count_a
Counter({1: 4, 2: 3, 3: 3})
```

The `Counter` object works like a dictionary. From there, you can sample how many percentage of each element you want, i.e.,

```
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> train_fraction = 0.7
>>> train = list(chain.from_iterable([[i]*int(max(count_a[i]*train_fraction, 1)) for i in count_a.keys()]))
>>> train
[1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3]
```